# Insert a Python list of lists in MySQL

Tags: python, numpy, mysql-python

I have a huge list (A) comprising of multiple sub lists (x, y, ... n), with each sub-list containing ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] elements. I want to transfer all the content of all the sub lists to a db table (using MySQLdb module) but not able to figure out how to achieve this. What I am doing right now is like this:

```
 import MySQLdb

 db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","test")
 cursor = db.cursor()

 for u in A:
     for x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8 in u:
           cursor.execute("INSERT INTO logs(date, time, pri, method, action, client, unknown1, unknown2) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" % (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8))
           db.commit()

 db.close()
```

But having no success..any help?

Comment: Where does it fail? Keep in mind that, according to [this PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) it is better to leave the actual encoding to the database interface, i.e. `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO LOGS(foo, bar) VALUES (%s, %s);", (foo, bar))`. Likewise, you can probably do something like `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO logs(date, time, pri, method, action, client, unknown1, unknown2) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);", u)`. Also the PEP above defines `executemany` which might be more appropriate for what you are trying.

Comment: It raises this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:data.py", line 38, in <module>
    for x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8 in u:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: I can't believe I am not having any answer. :-)

Comment: Your error is not MySQL related: each of the elements of the `u`s you are extracting from `A` in your for loop are a sequence of more than 8 elements, so when Python tries to assign them to your `x1, ..., x8` it has "too many values to unpack". Add a `print u[0]`right after the `for u in A:` to see how many variables you really need.

Comment: try this
`for x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8 in u.iteritems():`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the line comment out is correct in your logic?

```
 for u in A:
     #for x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8 in u:
           cursor.execute("INSERT INTO logs(date, time, pri, method, action, client, unknown1, unknown2) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" % (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8))
```

You are more likely to do like this:

```
 import MySQLdb

 db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","test")
 cursor = db.cursor()

 cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO logs(date, time, pri, method, action, client, unknown1, unknown2) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", A)
 db.commit()

 db.close()
```

Use **%s** in executemany will let the MySQLdb do the dirty work(escape string to 'string', but keep int as int, etc. For example "str" -> "'str'", "1"  -> 1).